# What is the purpose of standardization in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, nearest-neighbour

I'm just getting started with learning about K-nearest neighbor and am having a hard time understanding why standardization is required. Reading through, I came across a section saying

> When independent variables in training data are measured in different
>   units, it is important to standardize variables before calculating
>   distance. For example, if one variable is based on height in cms, and
>   the other is based on weight in kgs then height will influence more on
>   the distance calculation.

Since K nearest neighbor is just a comparison of distances apart, why does it matter if one of the variables has values of a larger range since it is what it is.

Also,what exactly does standardization do to the values? One of the formulas does it by Xs = (X-mean)/(max-min) Where does such a formula come from and what is it really doing? Hopefully someone can offer me a simplified explanation or give me a link to a site or book that explains this in simple terms for beginners.

Comment: If you are citing text from a book, lecture notes, article, or whatever, then *please add a reference* so proper credit is given to the author.